# Track name and list elements and give them default values extracted from a file: Python

Tags: python, matrix

```
Input file format is like below: 

 Label A
{
  Zebra,
  Lion,
  Python,
  Cat,
  Dog,
  Blah,
}
 Label B
{
  India,
  Nigeria,
  Malaysia,
  Peru,
}
```

I want to assign a default value to these elements, I was thinking I will form a multi-dim list/array and then it would be easy to assign. Right now I have the name and the elements in a variable.

```
Code: 

from numpy import *

for match in re.finditer(r'Label (\w+)\s+([^\n]+)\s*\{(.*?)\}', input_file_read, re.DOTALL):
    Group_name = match.group(1)
    Group_elements = str(match.group(3).strip())
    ele_names = Group_pins.split(',')
    ele_list = [ele.strip() for ele in ele_names]
    ele_array.extend(pins_list)
print ele_array

To the above code I also tried: 

ele_matrix = np.array(ele_array)

Output: 
ele_array = ['Zebra','Lion','Python','Cat','Dog','Blah','India','Nigeria','Malaysia','Peru']
```

I want:

```
([A, Zebra, Default_value]
[A, Lion, Default_value]
[A, Python, Default_value]
[A, Cat, Default_value]
[A, Dog, Default_value]
[A, Blah, Default_value]
[B, India, Default_value]
[B, Nigeria, Default_value]
[B, Malaysia, Default_value]
[B, Peru, Default_value])
```

It should be a **single matrix**, with **n*3** where **n** is the **total elements** in both the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
import re

# Reading File Data
handle = open("input.txt", "r")
input_file_read = "".join(handle.readlines())
handle.close()
# print input_file_read
_PATTERN_ = re.compile('^[\s]*Label[\s]*(\w)+[\s\n\{]*([^\}]+)', re.MULTILINE);
_DEFAULT_VALUE = 1
_Myarray = []
for match in _PATTERN_.finditer(input_file_read):
    Group_name = match.group(1).strip()
    # print Group_name
    elements = match.group(2).replace(',', '').split()
    # print elements
    # _Myarray.append([Group_name, i, _DEFAULT_VALUE] for i in elements)
    for i in elements:
        _Myarray.append([Group_name, i, _DEFAULT_VALUE])

print _Myarray
```

Comment: @ DOOM: I need to process only the lines which has Lable A / Label B however the file has a few lines initially which are in a different format which I am ignoring. That is why I had the regex. Do we need a if statement for thsi to work then?? I modified the code for your reference.

Comment: @Doodle: I am not sure about the regex since you have the original text . But the regex u used doesn't work with the sample input text

Comment: @ DOOM Thanks! I was not aware that we could form array like you have mentioned.